# discord.js have an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making help a panel that uses `loader.js` to load all the desc of my commands, but I have struggled fixing the error:

```js
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");

const loadCommands = (client, dir = "./commands") => {
    readdirSync(dir).forEach((dirs) => {
        const commands = readdirSync(`${dir}/${dirs}/`).filter((files) => files.endsWith(".js"));

        for (const file of commands) {
            const getFileName = require(`../${dir}/${dirs}/${file}`);
            client.commands.set(getFileName.help.name, getFileName);
            console.log(`[Command loaded]: ${getFileName.help.name}`);
        }
    });
};

const loadEvents = (client, dir = "./events") => {
    readdirSync(dir).forEach((dirs) => {
        const events = readdirSync(`${dir}/${dirs}/`).filter((files) => files.endsWith(".js"));

        for (const event of events) {
            const evt = require(`../${dir}/${dirs}/${event}`);
            const evtName = event.split(".")[0];
            client.on(evtName, evt.bind(null, client));
            console.log(`[Event loaded]: ${evtName}`);
        }
    });
};

module.exports = {
    loadCommands,
    loadEvents,
};
```

Every time I tried to run the code, it throws the following error:

```
     client.commands.set(getFileName.help.name, getFileName);
                                           ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I already put the export modules at the end of the commands, for example:

```js
module.exports.help = {
    name: "membercount",
    aliases: ['membercount', 'membercounter'],
    category: 'other',
    description: "get the amount of guild members in CheatAway",
    cooldown: 3,
    usage: '',
    example: [],
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look carefully at the documentation [here](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#loading-command-files) under loading-command-files. getFileName is not being set correctly which is why the error is being thrown.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).